# Proving Proposition with Predicate Logic

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

If we have the proposition

\begin{align}
&\text{Bob is a Babylonian}\\
&\text{Bob is a Human}\\
&\text{Therefore, some Humans are Babylonians}
\end{align}

which translates to

\begin{align}
&B(p)\\
&H(p)\\
&\text{Therefore, } \exists x (B(x) \land H(x))
\end{align}

how would one prove such a proposition? Would it look something like

**EDIT**

\begin{align}
&B(p) ... (\text{premise a})\\
&H(p) ... (\text{premise b})\\
&\text{Therefore, } B(p) \land  H(p) ... (1) \text{ by premise a and b}) \\
&\text{Therefore, }\exists x (B(x) \land H(x)) ... (2) \text{ by (1)}
\end{align}

Comment: Not correct: first $B(p) \land H(p)$ and then $\exists x (B(x) \land H(x))$ otherwise the two $\exists$s can be two different objects.

Comment: Ok, I believe I understand now. I will update my edit to reflect my thinking.

Answer (score 0):

It is *predicate logic*; thus, we need the rules for managing *quantifiers*.

The details depend on the proof system you are using... but basically we have to use the principle of [Existential generalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Existential_generalization).

From $B(p)$ and $H(p)$ we get $B(p) \land H(p)$ by propositional rules (specifically : [Conjunction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunction_introduction)), that means that "object $p$ is both $B$ and $H$".

Then we can conclude that "there is something that is both $B$ and $H$".

Comment: Would the edit then suffice as a proof since I have now included the $\exists$ - intro rule?