# Predicate logic proof (some a are b, some a are c, therefore there exists some c)

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

For the syllogism:

```
Some A are B
Some A are C
------------
There exists C
```

*Something like: My cake is pink, My cake is round, there exist things that are round*

We get ?:

$\exists x (A(x) \land B(x)) \land \exists x(A(x) \land C(x)) \implies \exists x(C(x))$

How would I go about proving that predicate?

Comment: The above is **not** a syllogism.

Comment: Having said that, from "Some A are C", that is $\exists x (A(x) \land C(x))$, it follows : $\exists x C(x)$.

Comment: According to you example : if "there is a Cake (your Cake) that is Round" then obviously "there is something (your Cake) that is Round".

Comment: To prove it use [rules for existential quantifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Existential_instantiation) and[Simplification rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunction_elimination). See [similar post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3184859/proving-proposition-with-predicate-logic).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a natural deduction proof using a Fitch-style proof checker:

[image]

Since $A$ is used to code $\forall$ in this tool, I replaced $A$ with $P$.

The proof uses in this order conjunction elimination, existential introduction and existential elimination.

---

Kevin Klement's JavaScript/PHP Fitch-style natural deduction proof editor and checker http://proofs.openlogicproject.org/